# Does everyone say the piyut addressing Af beri?

Tags: nuschaot, malach-angel, musaf, shmini-atzeres, yotzrot

According to the opinion that Machnisei Rachamim should not be said as we don't pray to angels, is there a problem to address Af Beri? I haven't heard of anyone skipping that piyut.

Comment: Af Beri isn't addressed, just described (at least in the Nusach I'm familiar with) so perhaps that is a distinction with Machnisei Rachamim.

Comment: @Yishai The last two lines are suspect. After mentioning how אף ברי brings rain we said לבל יעצרו בנשיון שטר, that it not be held back as payment of of our owed debt of sin. Sounds like we are adressing him. The next line is leaning towards this even more אמונים גנון בם שואלי מטר, protect in the merit of the faithful (Patriarchs), those who pray for rain. This translation is based on Artscroll's interlinear siddur.

Comment: Your question and its title don't match. Normally, I'd edit the title to match the question, but in this case the title has an answer (posted below) so I'm uncomfortable doing that. Can you please clarify whether you in fact meant to ask your question ("According to the opinion that Machnisei Rachamim should not be said as we don't pray to angels, is there a problem to address Af Beri?") or merely whether anyone skips it (as your title says and as is answered below), by [edit]ing the question?

Comment: @msh210 I realised that when I got an answer that only answer half my question. My main inquiry was if anyone specifically addressed the praying to angels issue involved with the piyut. But I did gain some knowledge from Danny and also felt bad being mivatel his answer limaphreia by editing my title.

Answer (score 2):

The *Nussach HaGra* as practiced by the Perushim (Talmidim of the Vilna Gaon in Jerusalem) as well as many Litvishe (Haredi) Yeshivot in Israel do not say this - nor almost any other Piyut (except on Rosh HaShana and Yom Kippour).

Their Tefilat-Geshem consists of a few *snippets* of the original, and is said before the silent Mussaf on Shmini Atzeret.

You can see the full text [here](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01774.html#HtmpReportNum0127_L2). The line starting with יַטְרִיחַ is not said.

(I have no idea what Nussach the Siddur in the link is, but they also do not say *the piyut addressing Af beri*.)

Comment: The siddur in the link say that it is Nusach Sepharad (Minhag Ashkenazim) or Sefard.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt - I saw that too - that's about as useless info as one could get, as almost each Chasidus has it's own variation. Is it Chabad? Boston/Berditchev? Ger? Etc...

Comment: See comments on the question. (This answer doesn't answer the question.)

Comment: @Danny did any of the sources you found mention why they don't say it?

Comment: @msh210 - this is not the question I answered - either it was merged with a similar one or edited. This keeps on happening to me; making we wonder if I should always quote the question in my answers.

Comment: @user6591 - no, it's rare that omissions are explained.

Comment: I don't *think* there was a merger. And you can see [the revision history of the question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/47538/revisions) yourself.